# Is $((A\to B)\to B)\to A$ a tautology?

Tags: logic

I'm really new to logic and I'm wondering whether the formula above is a tautology.

I know that a tautology is a statement that's always true. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $A$ is false and $B$ is true, then the formula is false.

Comment: Thank you! It seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 3):

It may be informative to convert your original expression to [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form):
$$
[(A\to B)\to B]\to A\equiv(\neg A\land\neg B)\lor A.
$$
Thus, you can see the counterexample Shaun gave is actually the *only* counterexample for which your desired implication is not true; that is, any other choice of truth values for $A$ and $B$ will result in a true implication.